# Why must FFmpeg's af_atempo filter be in the [0.5, 2.0] range?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

When I tried to use this filter with FFmpeg, I found the audio tempo argument must be in this range [0.5, 2.0].

But I don't understand why the audio tempo filter's argument has to be in this range.

Why does it have to be in this range?

Comment: You'll have to inspect the [source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/af_atempo.c) to discover that. Workaround is to chain multiple atempo filters to get resulting ratio.

Comment: Thx a lot. this helpful

Answer (score 6):

The [atempo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atempo) filter now has a range of 0.5-100:

[lavfi/atempo: raise max tempo limit](https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?a=commit;h=29cddc99cd8302e462bbae572e885e88f63d6dc3)

Comment: the atempto has problems but Im not gonna go through the register process - just noting it - it produces artifacts at the beginning.

Comment: @gpasch You may get better results with the [rubberband filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rubberband) (or the standalone `rubberband` tool).

Answer (score 5):

The reason that the `af_atempo` filter requires between 0.5 and 2.0 (inclusive) is because of it's underlying algorithm. `af_atempo` uses the 'WSOLA' algorithm (Waveform Similarity Based Overlap-Add) to change the audio's timescale without changing pitch, and those limits are as a result of the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 2):

An easy, but inefficient workaroun is cascading multiple tempo filter, here is an example that speeds video and audio by 4

```
ffmpeg -i input.MP4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.25*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0,atempo=2.0[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Comment: Seems there's no other option! And you're right, truly inefficient. This means to slow it down for example by 100 times, `atempo` has to be applied 7 times (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻